# Allowing access to only a single file in AWS S3 from IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to allow access to only a particular file within a S3 folder & tried below IAM policy

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketTagging",
            "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:GetBucketLogging",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
            "s3:GetIntelligentTieringConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls",
            "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:GetObjectRetention",
            "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
            "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
            "s3:GetBucketNotification",
            "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
            "s3:GetBucketCORS",
            "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bucket/folder1/folder2/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bucket/folder3/folder4/my_file.csv",
        ]
    }
]
```

I am able to read all objects inside folder2 but while trying to read the my_file.csv inside folder4 it is not able to fetch it. Is there something wrong with the syntax ? I tried multiple ways but couldn't figure out how to restrict to read only a particular file .

Comment: Your `Resource` appears correct. How did you attempt to "read" that file? (By the way, only `s3:GetObject` is required if you simply want to allow the user to retrieve the object.)

Comment: Hi John , we are trying to programmatically read via API calls , issue is that for a specific ARN it is not working (eg: test.csv) but if we give access to everything under than arn it works (eg: Folder/*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS Policy Generator for it if you don't know how to write and you can have something like this.

```
{
  "Id": "VisualEditor0",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1634859177800",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bucket/folder3/folder4/my_file.csv",
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1634859274600",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bucket/folder1/folder2/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Joiltos , Thank you ! we have already tried something like that but it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

This policy worked for me:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/folder3/folder4/my_file.csv"
        }
    ]
}
```

I put that **policy on an IAM User**, then used the AWS CLI (as that user) with:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/folder3/folder4/my_file.csv -
```

It successfully printed the file to my screen that I had uploaded under that name. (The hyphen sends it to stdout.)